# Android How schedule task for every night with JobDispatcher api?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

i have to download json response from web server on every night,previously i have used `AlarmManager` for scheduling tasks but i think for this kind of situation [`JobDispatcher`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) is great because it auto perform task if network available so i don't have to manage this kind of stuf.But i have found many examples of `JobDispatcher` and `JobScheduler` in all of them a simple job is scheduled or scheduled for some time delay but there is nothing relevant to my requirements,
if anyone have idea of this please help or provide any link related to this, it will be very helpful.

**UPDATE**

**1.** **How to make this to work every night,because currently it is only set alarm to midnight for once , how to make it repeted for every night at same time ?**

Comment: using AlarmManager  if your app is killed it will also kill the alarm in some phones

Comment: @phpdroid `AlarmManager` have some problems therefore I am using `JobDispatcher`

Comment: @KulwinderSinghRahal Did you solve? if yes then please post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you need to schedule time-based jobs

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher jobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(
                new GooglePlayDriver(this));

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar midNight = Calendar.getInstance();
midNight.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
midNight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
midNight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
midNight.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
midNight.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - midNight.getTimeInMillis();

if (diff < 0) {
    midNight.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    diff = midNight.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
}

int startSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000); // tell the start seconds
int endSencods = startSeconds + 300; // within Five minutes 

Job networkJob = jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
        .setService(NetworkJob.class)
        .setTag(NetworkJob.ID_TAG)
        .setRecurring(true)
        .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(startSeconds, endSencods))
        .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
        .setReplaceCurrent(true)
        .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
        .build();

jobDispatcher.schedule(networkJob);
```

Comment: thanks for help,but I know about this my question is how to schedule this task to be performed every night after 12 am

Comment: @KulwinderSinghRahal purpose of Job Scheduler or Job Dispatcher is run based on constraint instead of time-based operations. Stil you use the `setTrigger()` for time-based.

Comment: yes ,then what value I should set in `setTrigger` to set job for every night , this is my actual question

Comment: @KulwinderSinghRahal update the answer to meet your requirements

Comment: I think this will work, also If I am not wrong we need to set `midNight.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);` to  `midNight.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);`

Comment: Oh yeah, @KulwinderSinghRahal your right it's AM only.

Comment: I want to know what will happen if device is not connected to network(Internet) at time(12:00 AM).Does it wait for device to connect network,if yes then how much time it will wait ?. network is very important because I have to perform task on network

Comment: it throws `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window start can't be less than 0` when scheduling task,i have set to be 15 minutes from now  in Calendar instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152771/discussion-between-vinayaga-sundar-and-kulwinder-singh-rahal).

Comment: hey i have update my question ,any help regarding this

Comment: You need to consider the date with the above logic.

Comment: thanks it would work , but what about issue number 1 that i posted on question ,please help me on that then I'm able to accept the answer

Comment: can you please specify what have to be entered in endWindow , because when i enter eg-:200 then it restarts Service after 200 seconds but what i want that service would restart Next night at same time

Comment: You need to recreate service again. So don't create a recursive service

Comment: what should i do to make service non recursive and where to start service again , please update answere if you like and also it is helpful for others in future

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set your JobDispatcher to start at the next midnight, ie set the start time as the difference between now and the next midnight. Once it starts you can let it start a new Job that starts in 24 hours, ie the service will start a new Job with start time set as 24 hours and make this one recurring.